# Dynamics CRM online report: advanced find view filtering

Tags: reporting-services, report, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I have to modify the filter of the advanced find view that is opened when I open a report. In the Visual Studio solution I only see the report's ssrs parameters,  i.e. the ones that you have to fill later, just before displaying the report's data.

How can I modify the advanced find filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question right, you are looking for the option to edit the Query you used to build the report.

For that, you have to download the rdl file from CRM, then add/open it in Visual Studio BI project. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/126893)

Once opened, you will see Datasets similar to Parameters, try to edit the Dataset. This should have fetchxml query downloaded/built using Advanced Find.

Check the Query Builder, you can edit the query used in this window.
[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/threadpunter/archive/2017/09/26/ssrs-reports-for-dynamics-365-using-fetchxml)

[image]